# Integration to get expected mean and variance

Tags: integration, statistics, statistical-inference

I have the following question:

The times in minutes needed to collect the tolls from motorists crossing a toll bridge
has the probability density function
$$f(x) = 2 exp(−2x), 0 ≤ x < ∞$$
A motorist approaches the bridge and counts 50 vehicles waiting in a queue to pay the toll.
Only one toll booth is in operation. Use the central limit theorem to find the approximate
probability that a motorist will have to wait more than 25 minutes before reaching the
front of the queue.

In my answer book it says it uses integration by parts to get $$E[X]=1/2$$ and $$Var[X]=1/4$$

Can anyone explain how and why they did this? Surely integrating gets $$-exp(-2x)$$? Thanks

Comment: You are not just supposed to integrate the given function. Do you know the integral definition of $E[X]$ and $Var[X]$?

Comment: no could you expand please?

Comment: "expected mean" should be replaced by "mean" or ["expected value"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: In this case,

$$E[X] = \int_0^\infty xf(x)dx$$

$$Var(X) = \left(\int_0^\infty x^2f(x)dx\right) - (E[X])^2 = E[X^2]-(E[X])^2$$

Do you understand why the book says, use integration by parts?